# Get value after each occurrence of character in line of text

Tags: java

I am iterating through all lines of a file in java and extracting relevant data. There is one line in the file I am having trouble with. The line looks like as follows

```
"D|12345|TEST|This is a test|123|Test Data|"
```

I need to grab all the individual values separated by | into separate strings, ignoring the "D"
So

```
String a = 1234 
String b = TEST
```

etc.

There are multiple lines in the file but I am only concerned with the line that starts with D, how would I go about this? I have some sample code but I'm not good with substringing

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {

            File f = new File("src/main/resources/data.txt");

            List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(f, "UTF-8");

            for (String line : lines) {
                if (line.startsWith("D")) {
                    // this iis the line i am concerned about
                    // not sure how to get each value from the line
                    int ind = line.lastIndexOf("|") + 1;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `String#split`?

Comment: Use `split("\\|")`

Comment: I don't want to be rude but this is pretty basic stuff so for the next time I suggest you browse through the documentation for the relevant class, String in this case, to see what methods are available.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly get a `String[]` from the `String` by using the method `split(...)`, see this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String line = "D|12345|TEST|This is a test|123|Test Data|";

    String[] splitLine = line.split("\\|");

    for (String word : splitLine) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

If you want to ignore the first column (the `"D"`), then take a classic `for` loop and start at index 1:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String line = "D|12345|TEST|This is a test|123|Test Data|";

    String[] splitLine = line.split("\\|");

    for (int i = 1; i < splitLine.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(splitLine[i]);
    }
}
```

You can basically loop through the lines of the file (as you already do) and only add the line to your `List<String>` if it `startsWith("D")` and ignore all the other ones. Then you take that `List<String>`, loop or stream (through) it and split each line as shown in the examples. Best would be a class / POJO that holds the values in order to store them.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is "split" the line into multiple Strings:

```
line.split("\\|");
```

It will return you an array with all your substrings:

```
String[] words = line.split("\\|");
```

So when you want to ignore the first "D" you can just ignore the first entry in your array (`words[0]` <- "D")

```
 D|12345|TEST|This is a test|123|Test Data|

 String[] words = line.split("\\|");

 words:
 ["D", "12345", "TEST", "This is a test", "123", "Test Data"];
```

**EDIT**

As deHaar pointed out, I forgot about the special character `|` , which splits the *line* in its single characters. So in *your case* you have to "escape" the `|` by putting a backslash before it. (but since the backslash is als a control character you have to escape it as well) so "\\|"

For most other ("normal") characters like say the whitespace `" "` or just `"a"` you wouldn't need to do that.

**EDIT2**

since I made so many errors in my answer, let my show you *one way* to get rid of the "D":

```
String words = line.substring(1).split("\\|");
```

The additional `substring(1)` will return the "sub string" starting at the second character (the character with index `1`) - so everything that comes after your "D".

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that

Comment: Hehe, I made that mistake before posting an answer myself ;-) It's a regular expression and a pipe must be escaped there... Additionally, you have skipped the `"D"` in your result, but the code you posted wouldn't skip it.

Comment: OK, mentioning `substring` adds useful information, so +1

Answer (score 1):

`line.split("\\|");` will give you an array of strings. Then  ignore element at position 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String[] splittedStr=line.split("\\|");
```

Then you may iterate on each item of array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your string; then iterate on each value, omitting the first element.

**For loop version:**

```java
String[] values = line.split("\\|");

for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(values[i]);
}
```

**Stream version:**

```java
String[] values = line.split("\\|");

Stream.of(values)
    .skip(1)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```